# Upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04, now I can't login

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 19.04, grubrescue

I updated via terminal my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04. However, I had several problems with it:

Firstly, the starting screen was getting stuck because of GNOME. I have edited `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncommented

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

but nothing happened.

I then tried adding `nomodeset` in the GRUB screen, and I get past the initial screen, but now I am stuck again with the line:

```
[  89.248171] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: HSW/BDW HD-audio HDMI/DP requires binding with gfx driver
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you using regular GNOME-based Ubuntu or the Xfce-based flavor known as Xubuntu?  That impacts which routes to take in terms of resolving the matter.